# How to convert jsobject with attribute to Xml

Tags: javascript, xml, json, converters

i'm trying to convert an js object to xml string, and i have tried using below plugins

https://github.com/michaelkourlas/node-js2xmlparser

http://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/

If i give data like below

```
var data = {
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Smith"
};
```

it should give result like this

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <person firstName="John" lastName="Smith">>     
> </person>
```

They have said that adding 'underscode' or "@" prefix to the js property will make that property as an attribute but my js object is created dynamically, so i cannot add "underscode" or "@" before each attribute property.

Is there any other way to achieve what i want?

Answer (score 1):

> *my js object is created dynamically, so i cannot add "underscode" or "@" before each attribute property.*

Well in fact you *can* add an "@" before each property without too much trouble, so if that's the only thing stopping you from using the conversion utilities you linked to:

```
var data = {
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Smith"
};

var updatedData = {},
    k;    
for (k in data) {
    updatedData["@" + k] = data[k];
}    
// now pass updatedData to your XML generator.
```

Feel free to add a call to [`.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) in the loop if you think it's necessary.

> *Is there any other way to achieve what i want?"*

Well of course. To name just one way, you can write your own XML creation routine.